# Alpha masking a non square region python cv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array that has 0's where there is *not* an object, and 1's where there *is* an object.

`matrix.shape = (500, 425)`

I want to create a numpy array mask of shape `(500, 425, 3)` such that:

```
mask = np.zeros((500, 425, 3))
if matrix[x][y] == 0:
    mask[x][y] = np.array([0, 0, 0]) # Black pixel if no object
else:
    mask[x][y] = np.array([0, 255, 0]) # Green pixel if object
```

So that I have green pixels where the object are, black pixels everywhere else. How do I create this mask? Will this work correctly, such that if I use `cv2.addWeighted` to the image and the mask, the object will have a transparent green mask over it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're describing an "over" or "blend" image compositing operation. You can combine the images directly using your mask image.The general formula for combining two images in this way is:

```
A*alpha + B*(1-alpha)
```

Where A is the image being placed on top of image B. Alpha can be any value between black and white. Gray alpha values will make A appear transparent. It is usually easier to convert to a float image because the math is much easier when the values are between 0 and 1.

If you have image A (your source image) and image B (a green image) and your mask (matrix). You can overlay image B on top of image A using:

```
outimg[x][y] = (B[x][y] * matrix[x][y]) + (A[x][y] * (1-matrix[x][y]))
```

or if you want transparency:

```
#50% transparency
t = 0.5
outimg[x][y] = (B[x][y] * (matrix[x][y]*t)) + (A[x][y] * (1-(matrix[x][y]*t)))
```

If you want to put image A on top of image B you can just reverse the terms in the expression.

Here is an example of compositing image A (a flat green image) on top of image B (the source image) with a mask and transparency:

source image:

[image: lena]

mask image:

[image: lena_mask]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

i = cv2.imread('lena.bmp')
#convert to floating point
img = np.array(i, dtype=np.float)
img /= 255.0
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

j = cv2.imread('lena_mask.bmp')
#convert to floating point
mask = np.array(j, dtype=np.float)
mask /= 255.0
#set transparency to 25%
transparency = .25
mask*=transparency
cv2.imshow('img',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#make a green overlay
green = np.ones(img.shape, dtype=np.float)*(0,1,0)

#green over original image
out = green*mask + img*(1.0-mask)
cv2.imshow('img',out)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output image:

[image: output]

Comment: Great example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending `matrix` to `3D` and simply multiplying with the green colour triplet, like so -

```
matrix[...,None]*[0,255,0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [35]: matrix
Out[35]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])

In [36]: matrix[...,None]*[0,255,0]
Out[36]: 
array([[[  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

The second column signifying the green colour.

Please note that this is not alpha masking, which generally involves the fourth channel, but is a simple RGB masking.

Another approach with zeros based `initialization` and might be better on performance -

```
m,n = matrix.shape
out = np.zeros((m,n,3),dtype=np.uint8)
out[matrix==1,1] = 255 # green channel accessed with the last index being 1
```